# Cordova 3.5 template for C# windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, cordova-3, mobile-application

Running VS 2013 with Cordova 3.3 installed. Trying to develop app for windows phone 8.1. I want to use C# code as the native code . Unable to see option for windows phone 8.1 cordova template in New Project C#.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the c# template for Cordova projects where you can use the cordova js plugins and add your own c# custom plugins in a c# project:

Create project from CLI of node.js. The link for the same: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

While adding the platform choose wp8 this will create a folder named platform in your project directory. Inside the platforms folder open the wp8 folder. Inside there exists a project sln file. This is the c# cordova project. It contains the cordova plugins in c#. You can add more plugins to the same project from the CLI.